# Problem with my VHDL finite state machine

Tags: vhdl, rgb, xilinx, fsm

I'm trying to make a state machine that detects a high bit or low bit and send it to the next addressed state. For some reason, it seems that my FSM is stuck on state detect or something is making the FSM reset constantly. When I look in the Synth report is says that `din` is unused and some of my states are missing.

I am working in Vivado 2017.4 if that makes any difference. I tried changing what state if reset=1. For some reason, it seems that reset is enabled if I input a high or low.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;
entity FSM_convert is
    Port (    mclk : in  STD_LOGIC;
              reset: in STD_LOGIC;            
              dout : out STD_LOGIC;
              strtcnt : out STD_LOGIC;
              din : in STD_LOGIC;
              count0ho : out STD_LOGIC;
              count0lo : out STD_LOGIC;
              count1ho : out STD_LOGIC;
              count1lo : out STD_LOGIC;
              Led : out Std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
              count0h : in STD_LOGIC;
              count0l : in STD_LOGIC;
              count1h : in STD_LOGIC;
              count1l : in STD_LOGIC
              );
end FSM_convert;
architecture Behavioral of FSM_convert is
type state_names is (  t0h,t0l,t1h,t1l,detect);
signal state_reg, state_next: state_names; 

begin

Sync_process: process(mclk,reset)--
   begin

     if reset='0' then
        state_reg <=detect ;--detect
     elsif rising_edge(mclk) then
         state_reg <= state_next;   -- this is where the next state becoes `the new current state
     end if;
   end process;


    -- next-state logic -- using the current state and the inputs, determine `what the next state should be at the next
    --  rising edge of the FSM clock (clk)
    -- also determine outputs
CombinatorialProcess:   process(state_reg,din,count0h,count0l,count1h,count1l,reset)
   begin        
       count0ho <= '0'; -- set default values for all outputs and control `signals   
       count1ho <= '0';
       count0lo <= '0';
       count1lo <= '0';
       state_next <= detect;
       dout <= '0';
       Led <= x"0"; -- determine next state and outputs 
      case state_reg is

         when detect =>
           if din<= '0'  then      
            state_next <= t0h;
         else
             state_next <= t1h; 
         end if;
                 count0ho <= '1';
                 count1ho <= '1';
                 count0lo <= '1';
                 count1lo <= '1';
     Led <= x"1";

        when t0h =>        
           if count0h = '1' then
                         state_next <= t0l;
           else
                         state_next <= t0h;
           end if;
                dout <= '1';
           count0lo <= '1';
            Led <= x"2";
        when t0l =>        
          if count0l = '1' then
                         state_next <= detect;
          else
                         state_next <= t0l;
          end if;
           Led <= x"3";                
        when t1h =>        
           if count1h = '1' then
                         state_next <= t1l;
           else
                         state_next <= t1h;
           end if;
          dout <= '1';
         count1lo <= '1'; 
         Led <= x"4"; 
        when t1l =>      
           if count1l = '1' then
                        state_next <= detect;
           else
                        state_next <= t1l;
         end if;              
          Led <= x"5";             
        end case;
    end process;
end Behavioral;`
```

What should happen is that the detect state picks up the current value of `din` and sends it to a different state. What currently happens is it stays at whatever if reset='0' then

```
    state_reg <=detect ;
```

Comment: The operator less than or equal to (`if din<= '0'  then `) is only TRUE  when din equals '0' (UX01ZWLH- with positional values left to right of 0 to 8, see IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.2 Enumerated types, package std_logic_1164). Without a [mcve] readers can't determine if din is static or not connected. What states are missing, those that can be branched to? Simulate or chase down din.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe First synthesis FSM_convert as standalone module and read vivado synth warnings. If for example din is present in standalone module, then maybe other module that you wrote that drives it keep it low, so vivado synthesis removes it from entity RTL. Also watch for reset polarity across design, its common mistake to drive some modules with active high reset and other with active low...

----------EDIT-----------------------------------------------

Placed entity in vivado and only ports removed by synthesis are LED[3] port and strcnt. So if din is removed in rtl definetely its because of upper module or reset signals.

Comment: You don't need an "----EDIT----" marker. Anyone can see the edit history of your post.